# Inkscape: how to set black background?

Tags: color, inkscape, shapes

I need to set the background to black so I can work on some white artwork. What I do now is work the shape in another color (like blue or black) and fill with white when finished.

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322025/setting-background-color-pattern-of-inkscape-workspace-to-distinguish-transparen

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open the document settings (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>). Pick a black background color and you're done.

[image]